# Copying and Pasting Files with VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am using VBScript to look through a folder and copy all excel files within subfolders. The code works great until I run into a subfolder without an excel file in it. How can I get the code to simply skip any subfolders that do not contain excel files? Thanks

Here is the Code:

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ShowSubfolders FSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\jonathan\Documents\Prints Tester"), 3 
Const DestinationFile = "C:\Users\jonathan\Documents\TestEnd\*.xls"

'Script that goes into the subfolder to find the files for copying
Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder, Depth)
If Depth > 0 then
    For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
    'Wscript.Echo Subfolder.Path 
    Dim FolderPath
    FolderPath = Subfolder.Path
    Dim SourceFile 
    SourceFile = FolderPath & "\*.xls"  

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
       'Check to see if the file already exists in the destination folder
        If fso.FileExists(DestinationFile) Then
            'Check to see if the file is read-only
            If Not fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes And 1 Then 
                'The file exists and is not read-only.  Safe to replace the file.
                fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "C:\Users\jonathan\Documents\TestEnd\", True
            Else 
               'The file exists and is read-only.
               'Remove the read-only attribute
               fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes - 1
               'Replace the file
               fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "C:\Users\jonathan\Documents\TestEnd\", True
               'Reapply the read-only attribute
                fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes + 1
            End If
       Else
           'The file does not exist in the destination folder.  Safe to copy file to this folder.
           fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "C:\Users\jonathan\Documents\TestEnd\", True
      End If
    Set fso = Nothing

    ShowSubFolders Subfolder, Depth -1 
    Next
End if
End Sub
```

Comment: Worth a read here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585712/why-doesnt-fileexists-support-wildcards

Comment: @Dave Thanks for pointing me toward that post. All I had to do to make the code skip the folders without excel files in them was add in an "On Error Resume Next"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I read used what was recommended in this article mentioned by @Dave:

[Why doesn't FileExists support wildcards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585712/why-doesnt-fileexists-support-wildcards)

All I needed was an `On Error Resume Next` to get the code to keep running after an error. Here is the finished, working code that will skip folders that do not have excel files in them.

```
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ShowSubfolders FSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\jonathan\Documents\Prints Tester"), 3 
Const DestinationFile = "C:\Users\jonathan\Documents\TestEnd\*.xls"

'Script that goes into the subfolder to find the files for copying
Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder, Depth)
If Depth > 0 then
    For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
    'Wscript.Echo Subfolder.Path 
    Dim FolderPath
    FolderPath = Subfolder.Path
    Dim SourceFile 
    SourceFile = FolderPath & "\*.xls"  

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
       'Check to see if the file already exists in the destination folder
        If fso.FileExists(DestinationFile) Then
            'Check to see if the file is read-only
            If Not fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes And 1 Then 
                'The file exists and is not read-only.  Safe to replace the file.
                fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "C:\Users\jonathan\Documents\TestEnd\", True
            Else 
               'The file exists and is read-only.
               'Remove the read-only attribute
               fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes - 1
               'Replace the file
               fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "C:\Users\jonathan\Documents\TestEnd\", True
               'Reapply the read-only attribute
                fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes = fso.GetFile(DestinationFile).Attributes + 1
            End If
       Else
           'The file does not exist in the destination folder.  Safe to copy file to this folder.
           On Error Resume Next
           fso.CopyFile SourceFile, "C:\Users\jonathan\Documents\TestEnd\", True
      End If
    Set fso = Nothing

    ShowSubFolders Subfolder, Depth -1 
    Next
End if
End Sub
```